# Django/Jquery PreventDefault works only with the first item on for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I'm trying to use Jquery PreventDefault to use some AJAX on my django blog post for loop but the PreventDefault works only with the top post only

### template

```
{% for posts in list %}
   #{{ posts.title }} and other stuff goes here
    <a href=""  data-href="  " id="like-btn"></a>
    <span data-likes=" {{ posts.like.count }} " id="{{posts.id}}" > {{ posts.like.count }} </span>
{% endfor %}
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#like-btn").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
    })
```

The preventDefault works fine with the first post but it doesn't work with any other post.

Comment: Deal with class, not id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a javascript/html problem and had nothing to do with django. The id attribute of a DOM element is supposed to be unique. Thus You4 #like-btn uniquely identifies a single like button. Which in your case turns out to be the very first like button. Your HTML should change to

```
{% for posts in list %}
   #{{ posts.title }} and other stuff goes here
    <a href=""  data-href="  " class="like-btn"></a>
    <span data-likes=" {{ posts.like.count }} " id="{{posts.id}}" > {{ posts.like.count }} </span>
{% endfor %}
```

And then your js to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".like-btn").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault()
})
```